# Compiling C++ code in a browser extension

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath

I am working on a browser extension in Firefox to intercept HTTP requests and alter them. Due to the purpose of my project, I would need to incorporate a project that's built in C++ in order to process that information. Rewriting the C++ project would take too much work (it's a big project). I read that I could make the C++ code into a .dll file and use that, but I am unsure on how to do this (kind of new to programming extensions. Did do a lot of web dev tho).

I have been doing a lot of research, and NPAPI seems to be the way to go (I know it's being phased out, but the project is just a proof of concept that I need working). However, I'm not sure whether frameworks like FireBreath can do extensions. It also needs to be in Firefox, since my company doesn't use anything else.

Is there a good method of accessing the C++ code in an extension? I'd love some links to tutorials if there are any. I did read [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731872/cross-browser-extension-development-in-c), but it didn't give a solid conclusion on what to use. Also, if there's a better/easier way to do this (plugins, etc), I'd love to know!

Sorry if this is in the wrong forum. Still new here :S

Comment: Did you consider [FastCGI](http://fastcgi.com/), [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol),  or using an HTTP server library in C++ (like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) etc...)? Why do you need to work inside the browser? Why not inside an HTTP server or proxy?

Comment: I'm relatively knew to this and don't know what those are... My C++ code takes the HTTP request data, encrypts it, and then sends it back to the browser, and then users who input data (ex: random textboxes) won't know that it's being encrypted. Could these do what I'm looking for?

Comment: I believe you need to learn quite a lot before coding. Take time to learn more about HTTP (and follow all the links I gave you)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that you should absolutely check all other possibilities before going with this one.  I'd probably look at writing your own proxy server (similar to how [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) works) that when it's running it does whatever you want done.

FireBreath can be used to create plugins, and only to create plugins.  *however*, you can use a plugin inside an extension, at least for now (you already know about the planned phasing out).  Thus if you can capture the data using the extension (and I don't know extensions, so I'm not sure if you can or not) then you could pass it into a plugin instance using your javascript extension in order to do the processing that you want to do.

Rule of thumb, though: ***If it can be done in any other way than a plugin, `don't use a plugin`.***

Answer (score 1):

@taxilian is right to say:

> If it can be done in any other way than a plugin, don't use a plugin.

Writing an actual Firefox extension would be more suitable. These days you're recommended to use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) to interface with binary blobs (DLL, so, dylib). What you would do:

- Write most of your add-on in Javascript, because that is how it is usually done and because it is the easiest way. There are ways to intercept, modify and trace http request/response e.g. the [http observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) are kinda an entry point to that. Have a look at MDN and other code (other add-ons) that manipulate HTTP requests to see how the different pieces (observers, `nsIHttpChannel`, `nsITracableChannel`
- Create a C-only API for your existing library, wrapping the C++ API that you need to access for your add-on. General rule of thumb: Keep it simple.
- Compose [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) bindings to that C-only API, so that you can use it from Javascript and use those bindings in your other extension code.